# How to Serialize/Deserialize array of bytes?

Tags: solidity, web3js, arrays, web3j

I'm writing a smart contract and inevitably need to have arrays of bytes as input and output of functions. In remix arrays work just fine but with `web3j` and `web3js` there are several issues with arrays which make it impossible to have array as inputs and outputs.

So I think I need some sort of `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` implementation in solidity to convert array of bytes to string and vice versa to get strings in input, work with arrays inside EVM and return strings in output.

Is there any clean and cost-effective implementation of such functions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> with web3js there are several issues with arrays which make it impossible to have array as inputs and outputs

No, this is definitely possible.

**If you're on web3 v0.x, then:**

- Use [`web3.fromAscii`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3fromascii) before you send the string to the smart contract
- Use [`web3.toAscii`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3toascii) after you read the string from the smart contract

**If you're on web3 v1.x, then:**

- Use [`web3.utils.asciiToHex`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#asciitohex) before you send the string to the smart contract
- Use [`web3.utils.hexToAscii`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#hextoascii) after you read the string from the smart contract

Comment: Thank you for response. These methods convert string to hex and vice versa. The issue is with arrays not strings. Strings works just fine.

Comment: @saman.shahmohamadi: You're gonna have to share you code, and explain what problems exactly you're having in sending byte arrays as input, or receiving them as output.

Comment: The issue is about **array of bytes** not **byte arrays**. First of all, solidity itself does not support arrays in inputs and outputs and you have to use experimental `ABIEncoderV2`. By the way this is another issue, now I'm looking for a serializer method in solidity.

Comment: @saman.shahmohamadi: English grammar: array of bytes = byte array.

Comment: It's about solidity not English. If you know solidity, you should know that we have **bytes** which is an array of multiple byte elements (in Java it called byte array). And we can make an array which contains that bytes elements. So in solidity **byte array** is called **bytes** and **array of bytes** is whole different thing.  
If you know the case you can test it on remix and you will see that you have to import `ABIEncoderV2`.

Comment: Just paste this code in remix and try to compile it.  


    `pragma solidity ^0.5.2;

contract TestArray {
    constructor() public {
    }
    
    bytes[] private bag;
    
    function put(bytes memory input) public {
        bag.push(input);
    }
    
    function pick() public view returns (bytes[] memory) {
        return bag;
    }
}`

Comment: @saman.shahmohamadi: Use `` to denote keywords. For example `bytes`. An array of `bytes` is essentially an array of arrays, which indeed cannot be passed from the off-chain or to the off-chain. It can, however, be passed from on-chain to on-chain (i.e., between functions in solidity). So again - please post your code (on-chain **and** off-chain), and denote what exactly is not working for you. Also - please do it in the question, not in a comment.